# Extract a part of the physical location

Tags: t-sql, substring

I need to extract the mount point of my backup location from the complete physical location of the file.

So for the file location as `X:\Backup\Vol1\MSSQL\XYZ\XYZ.bak` I need just `X:\Backup\Vol1` as result.

So basically I want the result upto the 3rd backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try chaining together a series of calls to `CHARINDEX` which can identify the third path separator from the start of the path:

```
SELECT
LEFT(path, CHARINDEX('\', path,
    CHARINDEX('\', path, CHARINDEX('\', path) + 1) + 1) - 1) AS out
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to trail down to a dynamic level

```sql
DECLARE @YourPath VARCHAR(1000)='X:\Backup\Vol1\MSSQL\XYZ\XYZ.bak';

DECLARE @level INT=3;

SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@YourPath,'\','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
       .query(N'
                for $fragment in /x[position()<=sql:variable("@level")]
                return <y>{concat("\",$fragment)}</y>
             ').value('substring(.,2,1000)','nvarchar(1000)');
```

The query will transform your path to an XML like

```
<x>X:</x>
<x>Backup</x>
<x>Vol1</x>
<x>MSSQL</x>
<x>XYZ</x>
<x>XYZ.bak</x>
```

The `XQuery` will pick all elements with a position `<=sql:variable("@level")` and return them with a leading `\`, thus leading to

```
<y>\X:</y>
<y>\Backup</y>
<y>\Vol1</y>
```

The final `.value()` will bring back *all at once* (due to the `XPath "."`).

```
\X:\Backup\Vol1
```

To get rid of the leading `\` I use `substring`, starting at the second character.